# Using hook_menu to add a child to a menu item

Tags: routes

So I create a menu item called Sponsorship in administration in the following way:

```
function eac_sponsorship_menu() {
  $items['admin/sponsorship'] = array(
    'title' => 'Sponsorship',
    'description' => 'This is where all of the child sponnsorship data is stored',
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access sponsorship section'),
    'plid' => 1,
    'weight' => -500,
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );
    return $items;
}
```

If I want to create another menu item directly after this, in the same function, how do I make it a child to this previously defined 'Sponsorship' menu item?

I have seen examples that use a DB lookup to get the plid value. This seems a bit counter intuitive bearing in mind I've only just created the Sponsorship menu item, is there a simple way to do this using the API?

**For example**

```
$items['admin/sponsorship/child'] = array(
  'plid' => //simple API function to get admin/sponsorship mid?
}
```

**Edit**

I think I've just answered my own question...I don't need to define plid, the path of the array $items is enough:

```
$items['admin/sponsorship/child']
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I think I've just answered my own question...I don't need to give plid, the path in $items is enough. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the url path should suffice for the default menu hierarchy there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example child item would just fall under the parent item in the path hierarchy, no need for plid.

e.g

```
  $items['admin/sponsorship/child'] = array(
    'title' => 'Sponsor child',
    'description' => 'This is where all of the child sponsorship data is stored',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_sponsor_child_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access sponsorship section'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );
```

[system_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_menu/7) has some good examples of menu item containers, using [system_admin_menu_block_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_admin_menu_block_page/7),  e.g `admin/appearance/*`

Make sure you clear menu cache to get any new menu item to show up there.

Comment: How about if you cannot have it naturally fall under the item, like in the case of <nolink> items?

Comment: Exactly, that is the same problem I am having DrCord. And I think the solution lies with specifying the "plid", but I'm not sure. I opened a new question regarding it, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646421/drupal-6-adding-sub-menu-items-on-a-menu-item

Comment: Sometimes you have to re-enable a module to make hierarchical changes effective.